# How to send browser notifications for specific users?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, notifications

I want to add browser notifications for my rails app.

I'm having trouble adding notifications to specific users.
For example, i have `user` and `lesson` models.
And I want to send notifications to the user about the beginning of the lesson.

But how do I send notifications, not to all users, but only to those related to the lesson?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is to get and store the subscription object for each user. Then, in your application, you should send a notification only for related users. 
There are a bunch of different gems for it, e.g. https://github.com/zaru/webpush